# Detect weaved class by aspectJ with byte-buddy agent

Tags: java, aspectj, agent, byte-buddy

I would like to verify that the code has been woven by aspectJ. One of the methods I've heard of is using agents from the byte-buddy library. Unfortunately, I am completely green in it and I do not know what I could do.

I tried to use JADE with agents, but byte-buddy is more friendly for myself and I think it's more suitable.

To verify the method I created a simple springboot application with MySQL connection and added some aspectJ code. I tried with Spring AOP, but AOP cannot read private methods, so I decided to provide my idea with aspectJ.

I already used another aspect to define joinPoints and throw an exception, but it's hard and takes a lot of works with the low results.

Do u have any ideas about methods or implementation of an agent with byte-buddy to detect aspectJ?

Comment: Byte Buddy let's you intercept and instrument code but you would need to detect any AspectJ specific behavior or byte codes to see if an instrumentation occurred. AspectJ, just like Byte Buddy, only instruments code. There is nothing "typical AspectJ" to find necessarily.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think this question is a good example for the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898). You explain **how** you want to do something instead explaining what you want to achieve? Why would you want to check if AspectJ has been woven in the first place? Are you writing an integration test? Or is it just that you don't trust the AspectJ compiler to do its job? I want to understand before I answer.

Comment: I wanted to have more expierncy with untrusted code. For exmaple if i get big project in Java and then I got some untrusted plugin with changes created by AspectJ, then I prefere to know whats to do to inspect that my classes are secured from AspectJ or that the AspectJ just woven my classes.

Answer (score 0):

First an answer to your comment:

> I wanted to have more experience with untrusted code. For example if I get a big project in Java and then I get some untrusted plugin with changes created by AspectJ, then I prefer to know what's to do to inspect that my classes are secured from AspectJ or that the AspectJ just weaves into my classes.

For AspectJ there are two scenarios:

- Compile-time weaving

  - Your application does not use AspectJ, no AspectJ Maven plugin in your Maven build or something similar in your Gradle build: Even if your third-party library is on the classpath, nothing gets woven into your own code. How could it? There is no AspectJ compiler.
  - Your application uses the AspectJ compiler: Even if the third-party library is on the classpath, no aspects are woven into your own code because you would have to explicitly put the library on the aspect path in order to achieve that. BTW, if the third-party library is aspect-enhanced, it will have a dependency on the AspectJ runtime *aspectjrt.jar*, otherwise it would not work. Even if the runtime was shaded into that other JAR, still nothing would happen to your own code.
- Load-time weaving

  - Your application does not use LTW: Obviously nothing would happen, no aspects from the other JAR could be woven into your code without you starting the JVM with an active weaving agent.
  - Your application uses LTW: You would need to provide an *aop.xml* file and there you can explicitly list aspects you want to be applied, which target classes or packages to include into or exclude from weaving, turn on `-showWeaveInfo` in order too see on the console which aspects are woven into which joinpoints. There is one caveat, though: If the AspectJ weaver finds more than one *aop.xml* or *aop-ajc.xml* files on the classpath, it will conceptually merge them. I.e. if the third-party library comes with such a file, it would be merged into your own as explained in the [AspectJ development guide](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw-configuration.html) (search for "several configuration files" on the page). So this could lead to some undesired side effects. The simplest thing to do if you want to inspect your third-party libraries is to scan the JARs for the presence of *aop.xml* or *aop-ajc.xml*, respectively. Then you can look at the content of those files, if any, and easily assess their possible effect on your code. But just checking the output of `-showWeaveInfo` on application start-up also reveals if unwanted aspects are woven into your own code.

---

So actually you don't need to scan for anything inside class files in order to detect AspectJ markers, but if you absolutely wish to here is something you can do:

Most AspectJ-woven classes contain fields or methods (can be static or non-static, private or public) with `ajc$` somewhere in their name, usually at the beginning. That's just a heuristic approach, but hey - whatever works, right?

- If I say "most classes" I mean that in some cases if an aspect only uses ITD in order to make a class implement an interface, introduce new methods or public fields, the class would just get the new elements but no AspectJ-specific code. But then they would just be normal classes, there is no cross-cutting advice code or whatever which could affect your own application.
- If you would find such members or fields, it would indicate that you either found classes enhanced by aspects (which could not affect your own classes even in the LTW scenario with extra *aop.xml*) or aspects themselves because they also contain the same markers plus some other stuff you could scan for.

So how can you scan those third-party class files?

- Command line: `javap -p path/to/MyClass.class | grep 'ajc[$]'`
- Java code to scan classes already loaded into your (test or inspection) application:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.lang.reflect.Member;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class AspectJDetector {
  public static boolean hasAspectJMarker(Class<?> clazz) {
    return Stream.concat(
      Stream.of((Member[]) clazz.getDeclaredMethods()),
      Stream.of((Member[]) clazz.getDeclaredFields())
    )
      .filter(member -> member.getName().contains("ajc$"))
      .findFirst()
      .isPresent();
  }
}
```

Just call `hasAspectJMarker(MyClassOfInterest.class)` for each class you want to check. If you find AspectJ-enhanced classes, there is again no need to worry. Only if you find aspects there might be. But as I said above: This would be easier to detect via *aop.xml* in that JAR. The XML file would even list the aspects explicitly via `<aspect name="com.MyAspect"/>`, basically a no-brainer.

Comment: I made some tests and now I see that the AspectJ is using static objects after woven methods. I tried use ur method but it's not actually works, becoues present false when i try to check class with woven method. Actually I used byte-buddy to present method if it is using and then print result about methods.. I found coummunication that method inside get two static reference with ```<init>``` and ```<cinit>```. That's not the best resolve, but actually works.

Comment: Of course my method works. Show me a case where is does not, don't just say it. Secondly, don't just claim to have found a better solution, write an answer sharing your code. That's what people do on StackOverflow. Last but not least, you could explain why you think you need that anyway because I explained in detail why you probably don't and that there are better ways to find out. My code was just a quick heuristic thing. Still you don't prove it wrong by just saying "it doesn't work". That's just weak. Let code speak.